# Babel discarding lining figures?

Tags: fonts, babel, oldstylenums, newtxmath, liningnums

I am using Baskervaldx’s Baskerville for main text with `osf` option and Newtx’s Times for math with `baskervaldx` option.

When `pdflatex` compiles without `babel` enabled, text figures are oldstyle and math figures are lining.
Since `babel` is enabled, all figures switch to oldstyle, which I don’t want for math…

How can oldstyle figures be kept for text, and lining for math?

---

MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[osf]{Baskervaldx}
\usepackage[baskervaldx]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

Baskervaldx text with old-style figures: 012345.

Math font is NewTXmath with baskervaldx option,
in \emph{inline math} ($x = 425^{28}$)
and \emph{display math:}

\[x = 425^{28}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? It does explain how to do this. I'm not sure that it will help, but you should at least see what it has to say.

Comment: @cfr: NewTX documentation advises to declare `babel` before `newtxtext` to avoid an `etoolbox` incompatibility. `Baskervaldx` also requires `etoolbox`, but this advice does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is strange that you do not mention looking at the documentation for `newtxmath`, which includes detailed instructions for using lining figures for maths and hanging for text, when Babel is used.

Unfortunately, they appear to be applicable only if the `newtxtext` fonts are used, although the documentation doesn't actually say so.

So the most straightforward option is probably to just rewrite the required configuration explicitly.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[osf]{Baskervaldx}
\usepackage[baskervaldx]{newtxmath}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {normal}{T1}{Baskervaldx-LF} {m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {bold}  {T1}{Baskervaldx-LF} {b}{n}

\begin{document}

Baskervaldx text with old-style figures: 012345.

Math font is NewTXmath with baskervaldx option,
in \emph{inline math} ($x = 425^{28}$)
and \emph{display math:}

\[x = 425^{28}\]

\end{document}
```

[image: tweaked font configuration]

Comment: Thank you, this works well. I’ll add that the `\SetSymbolFont` command usage is described in the Latex2e font selection guide at http://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/ .

Comment: @gwenj I copied it from `cfr-lm.sty` but, yes, I'm sure the NFSS documentation covers it, too.